# How can I parse data like this?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I work for a nursing home and they have tons of hand-picked scripture they would like to appear on their website. I received a text document with over 300 of them and would like to some how import the data instead of doing it by hand.

```
1. Matthew 8:1-4: Blah blah blah blah.
2. Mark 1:32-34: Blah blah. Blah, blah; blah.
.
.
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? I am using php.

For example, I would need two pieces of data from each line:

```
Matthew 8:1-4:
Blah blah blah blah.
```

Comment: what are you trying to parse?

Comment: Apparently the scripture name is between the first full stop and the second colon. The text is after the second colon. You shouldn't even need regex to parse that.

Comment: Maybe some info on what you expect to be the result of the parsing - and what you have tried yourself - would be helpful.

Comment: My mistake, for 1. I would want: "Matthew 8:1-4:" and "Blah blah blah blah.". I will edit that, thanks.

Comment: I have tried using split by space but some of the formating is not nice. I am a new programmer and looked at regex but I have issues trying to do it myself.

Comment: You have a list of verses, or will you be querying an api?  http://www.esvapi.org/api

Answer (score 2):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('~^[0-9]+\. ([^0-9]+ (?:[0-9]+:)?[0-9]+-[0-9]+:) (.+)$~', trim($line), $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Untested, but should do it.

Comment: Looking at that gives me a headache. It doesnt work for cases like: 56. 2 John 2-3: Blah blah. But I will try to do it myself, thanks for the start.

Comment: Because it never expects `2-3`, but always `123:2-3` (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: I know, I forgot to add that case in the question and you're right it works. I shall tweak your solution for what I need, I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you have only 300 lines, you'll probably get the thing faster done if you take a solution that works most of the time and handle special cases by hand.

Comment: @Juhana - If I had 300 lines of code to manipulate, I *would* try to find a way other than hand editing. It may not be faster immediately for less experienced coders, but over time with multiple attempts I would hope that would improve. You have to learn somehow. `:)`

Comment: No, I mean if the text file has 300 scriptures and this regex imports 280 of them correctly, you can just fix the rest manually instead of trying to get the code 100% perfect. Unless this is something you have to do continually and not just once.

Comment: @Juhana - Ah, I see what you mean. Learning aside, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Using `split()` (or `explode()`) to do what you're looking at doing. Note, the formatting itself of each line is critical, in that this is looking for the first `.` and the first `:`, so it will misfind

```
1.Matthew 8: 1-4: Blah Blah Blah.
```

To be honest, I think you'd be better off with a Regex here.

```
$kvs = array();
$str = "
1. Matthew 8:1-4: Blah blah blah blah Blah: blah.
2. Mark 1:32-34: Blah blah. Blah, blah; blah.
3. Mark 2:2-4: Blah blah. Blah, blah; blah.
";

$split = split("\n", $str);
$c_split = count($split);

print_r($split);

for ($i = 0; $i < $c_split; $i++) {
    if (trim($split[$i]) != '') {
        $key = substr($split[$i], strpos($split[$i], '. ') + 2, strpos($split[$i], ': ') - 3);
        $value = substr($split[$i], strpos($split[$i], ': ') + 2);

        $kvs[$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($kvs);
```

http://codepad.org/hq2LkMlr

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 1. Matthew 8:1-4: Blah blah blah blah Blah: blah.
    [2] => 2. Mark 1:32-34: Blah blah. Blah, blah; blah.
    [3] => 3. Mark 2:2-4: Blah blah. Blah, blah; blah.
    [4] => 
)
Array
(
    [Matthew 8:1-4] => Blah blah blah blah Blah: blah.
    [Mark 1:32-34] => Blah blah. Blah, blah; blah.
    [Mark 2:2-4] => Blah blah. Blah, blah; blah.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with explode rather than a regex:

```
$first_explosion = explode($line,".");
$interesting_data = $first_explosion[1]; #We ignore the number before the dot
$parsed_data = explode($interesting_data, ":",2); #Do just 2 "explodes", anything after the second ":" will be left alone
#$parsed_data is an array, element 0 is "Matthew 8", element 1 is "34-10", element 2 contains the rest
```

You can then manipulate the parsed_data array to end up with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to split each line could be:

```
$yourObjectArray = explode(".", $theLine);
// now $yourObjectArray[0] is the line number, $yourObjectArray[1] is the content
```

Then you could use a function like this to find the last `:` and split that up there.

```
function strlastpos($haystack, $needle) {   
  # flip both strings around and search, then adjust position based on string lengths 
  return strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle) - strpos(strrev($haystack), strrev($needle)); 
} 

$bookArray = split($yourObjectArray[1], strlaspost($yourObjectArray[1], ":"));
// now $bookArray[0] is your chapter/book information and $bookArray[1] is the content (blah blah)
```

`explode` document can be found here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php